# Anchor points should only visible when mouse goes over them

Tags: javascript, html, kineticjs

The code below creates a scalable and draggable triangle with anchor points at its vertices. i want that the anchor points should only visible when mouse goes over them??
and also, how collision detection can be implemented to avoid drawing of other spaces inside the triangle?

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/libraries/kinetic-v3.10.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      // the circle anchor points
      function buildAnchor(layer, x, y, name) {
        var anchor = new Kinetic.Circle({
          x: x,
          y: y,
          radius: 6,
          stroke: "#666",
          fill: "#ddd",
          strokeWidth: 2,
          draggable: true,
          name : name
        });

        // add hover styling
        anchor.on("mouseover", function() {
          document.body.style.cursor = "pointer";
          this.setStrokeWidth(4);
          layer.draw();
        });
        anchor.on("mouseout", function() {
          document.body.style.cursor = "default";
          this.setStrokeWidth(2);
          layer.draw();
        });

        layer.add(anchor);
        return anchor;
      }

      function buildTriangle(layer, points, name) {
        var triangle = new Kinetic.Polygon({
          stroke : "red",
          strokeWidth : 4,
          name : name,
          draggable : true
        });

        triangle.a = buildAnchor(layer, points[0], points[1], "anchor");
        triangle.b = buildAnchor(layer, points[2], points[3], "anchor");
        triangle.c = buildAnchor(layer, points[4], points[5], "anchor");
    triangle.was = { x : 0, y : 0 };

        layer.add(triangle);
        return triangle;
      }

      function drawTriangle() {
        var triangle = this.get(".triangle")[0];

        if ( !triangle.isDragging() ) { 
          triangle.setPoints([ triangle.a.attrs.x - triangle.was.x, 
                               triangle.a.attrs.y - triangle.was.y,
                               triangle.b.attrs.x - triangle.was.x,
                               triangle.b.attrs.y - triangle.was.y,
                               triangle.c.attrs.x - triangle.was.x,
                               triangle.c.attrs.y - triangle.was.y ]);
        } else {
          var anchors = this.get(".anchor");

          for ( var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i ++ ) {
            anchors[i].setX(anchors[i].getX() + (triangle.getX() - triangle.was.x));
            anchors[i].setY(anchors[i].getY() + (triangle.getY() - triangle.was.y));
          }

          triangle.was.x = triangle.getX();
          triangle.was.y = triangle.getY();
        }
      }

      window.onload = function() {
        var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
          container: "container",
          height: 200
        });

        var layer = new Kinetic.Layer({
          drawFunc : drawTriangle
        });

        var triangle = buildTriangle(layer, [60, 100, 90, 100, 90, 140], "triangle");
        triangle.moveToBottom();

        // add the layer to the stage
        stage.add(layer);
      }
    </script>
    <style>
      #container {
        border: 1px solid black;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body onmousedown="return false;">
    <div id="container"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Y9AtR/

Comment: This is essentially the code pasted from [this tutorial](http://tech.joshuacummings.com/2012/07/scalable-draggable-anchored-triangle-in.html) and it doesn't seem that you actually tried solving it yourself. Especially your first point is so simple that you would have found out on your own. http://jsfiddle.net/Y9AtR/1/

Comment: @Tomalak, i'am trying on it and near to solve it, for second point i'm not getting any idea to solve it.

Comment: Well point 1 is answered (see link in my comment above). For point 2 you can start with the answers that already exist on this topic. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=triangle+collision+detection+2d Once you try one of the ways described and run into problems, you should come back and ask a specific question.

Comment: PS: Also, next time please include a jsFiddle yourself, that makes life a lot easier for people.

Comment: @Tomalak: thnks, i will keep it in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like @Tomalak's solution, here is mine:

http://jsfiddle.net/Y9AtR/2/

```
triangle.on('mouseover', function(){
     triangle.a.show();
     triangle.b.show();
     triangle.c.show();
     layer.draw();
});

triangle.on('mouseout', function(){
     //if( not near triangle ) // add some logic so that they don't disappear right away, maybe use distance formula?
     triangle.a.hide();
     triangle.b.hide();
     triangle.c.hide();
     layer.draw();
})
```

Comment: Also, maybe you could be more specific about the collision detection problem you are having.